# How can I persist state in a VS Code WebviewPanel after it is destroyed?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

After looking at the [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/webview#_persistence), I'm able to persist state in the following two cases:

1. When a `WebviewPanel` is hidden (ie, the user switches tabs) using `getState`/`setState`
2. When the user restarts the VS Code by implementing a `WebviewPanelSerializer`

However, I don't see a way to persist state when the panel is destroyed (ie, the user closes it or calls `dispose`). Here's my scenario:

1. I execute a command to show the `WebviewPanel`
2. I have an input box in the HTML content. I type some string in and press a button to save it. Upon saving, I save it using `setState` and then append a `div` with the entered text into the webview.
3. I close the panel and execute the command again. The panel does not have the appended `div`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 2 options:

1. Recreate the additional div when you find saved state (e.g. the input from the user).
2. Use `retainContextWhenHidden` to keep the content of the webview, even if it is moved to the background.

The latter won't help when the user closed the webview, however, and is much more resource hungry than the state save/restore operation.

Comment: For the first option, how do I access the saved state after opening a new panel? Could another option be to store the data in `ExtensionContext.globalState`?

Comment: That's what I mean here. When the existing view is about to be closed store the user input in the global state. Then pass this value to the new view on opening, which can add a div with that content.